# Wann und wie muss man "usw" nutzen?

Tags: abbreviation

Ich weiß, dass "etc" auf Deutsch als "und so weiter" oder "usw" übersetzt wird. Ich sah es im Wörterbuch, aber ich habe es nie in der Realität gesehen. Man darf kein Komma vor "etc" im Englischen schreiben. Ist die Regel ähnlich auch im Deutschen vorhanden? Und ist ein Punkt danach nötig?

Comment: Danke Shi! Sie waren viele Fehler, dass ich schrieb. Aber jetzt habe ich eine Frage. Sie änderten den zweitletzen Satz und schrieben "vorhanden" am Ende. Warum taten Sie es? Können Sie mir seine Bedeutung erklären?

Comment: "Man darf kein Komma vor "etc" im Englischen schreiben." - das hängt abercstark davon ab, wen man fragt. In Richtlinien, die das "Oxford-Komma" verwenden, *muss* man vor "etc." im Englischen sogar oft ein Komma setzen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Das Kürzel oder die Abkürzung "etc." kommt vom lateinischen "et cetera" und bedeutet ins Deutsche übersetzt "und so weiter". "Und so weiter" kann mit "usw." abgekürzt werden, wobei Abkürzungen im Deutschen mit einem Punkt beendet werden. "Und so weiter" bzw. "usw." kommt durchaus häufiger in deutschsprachigen Dokumenten vor.

Wie Shi in seinem Kommentar bemerkt hat, ist es ein guter Stil, pro Dokument konsequent entweder nur "etc." oder nur "usw." zu verwenden.

Als Satzanfang sollte man keine Abkürzung verwenden, dann immer die Abkürzung ausschreiben. Man kann im Deutschen eine Abkürzung nach einem Komma schreiben, z. B. wie gerade eben. In einer Aufzählung hingegen (Kommentar von user unknown) wird vor "etc." oder "usw." kein Komma geschrieben, da [vor einem "und" kein Komma gesetzt wird](http://canoonet.eu/services/GermanSpelling/Regeln/Interpunktion/Komma/Aufzaehlung.html#Anchor-Wenn-35882).

Vergleiche:

> Erstens, zweitens und drittens.
>
> Erstens, zweitens usw.

Die Abkürzungen, die aus mehreren Wörtern bestehen ("zum Beispiel" wird zu "z. B."; "das heißt" wird zu "d. h.") werden einzeln abgekürzt und mit einem Spatium (halber Leerschritt, **kein Zeilenumbruch** erlaubt) getrennt. Die Schreibweise ohne (halber) Leerschritt ist **falsch**.

Ich persönlich versuche allerdings Abkürzungen nach Möglichkeit vollständig zu vermeiden.